# Scons custom builder by invoking python function does not work

Tags: python, builder, scons

I create a builder by invoking python function, the SConstruct code:

```
def compile_c(dsts, srcs, env):
  for (src, dst) in zip(srcs, dsts):
    print src, dst
    com2 = [
    "mkdir -p %s" % os.path.dirname(dst),
    "rm -f %s" % dst,
    "%s -M %s -Wno-error %s > %s.tmp" % (env['CC'], ' '.join(env['CFLAGS']), src, dst),
    "sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,%s/objects/c/\1.o %s : ,g' < %s.tmp > %s" % (env['RUNRULE_DIR'], dst, dst, dst),
    "rm -f %s.tmp" % dst
    ]
    for com in com2:
      print com
      if os.system(com):
        exit(1)
  return None
bld = Builder(action = compile_c)
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'Foo' : bld})
env["C_D"] = ['../RunRules/Simulation/objects/c/ThreeDAverageVariableCpuCode.d']
env["C_SRC"] = ['ThreeDAverageVariableCpuCode.c']
env.Foo(env["C_D"], env["C_SRC"])
```

The target file does not exist, but when I build it does not make any effect and ignore the print function:

```
awp-max/CPUCode ▸ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
awp-max/CPUCode ▸
```

The target file does still not exist.

Comment: Having your builder call os.system() is generally not recommended.

Any reason you're doing that rather than building command lines to be run/managed by SCons?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by modify env['C_D'] to absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a target that is outside your current directory. In this case you have to either specify the relative path to the target on the command line, e.g.:

```
scons ../RunRules/ThreeDAverageVariableCpuCode.d
```

or use an absolute path, as suggested in your own answer.

To read up on this topic, please visit our [FAQ page](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) and especially read the comments regarding #2 of our "most frequently asked FAQs" (you'll find a link right at the top of the page).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try this new method. It is my first time to ask a question and you are so fast.